# GeoFire Won't Stop Pulling Data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

For some reason when I use GeoFire to pull events it never seems to stop pulling events. I noticed when I left my computer for a little and came back and my array had 1000 elements in it.

```
static func showEvent(pageSize: UInt, lastPostKey: String? = nil, category: String? = nil,completion: @escaping ([Event]) -> Void) {
    //array that will hold events
    var currentEvents = [Event]()
    var currentEventKeys = [String]()
    //getting firebase root directory
    //create geofire ref to get current user location
    let geofireRef = Database.database().reference().child("userlocations")
    //create new geofire instance to actually pull event based off location
    //create geofire instance to handle the ref
    let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)
    let eventgeofireRef = Database.database().reference().child("eventlocations")
    let geoFire1 = GeoFire(firebaseRef: eventgeofireRef)

    //will get the location for of the current user from database
    //
    geoFire?.getLocationForKey(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid, withCallback: { (location, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("An error occurred getting the location for \"firebase-hq\": \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        } else if (location != nil) {
                            print("Location for \(String(describing: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)) is [\(String(describing: location!.coordinate.latitude)), \(String(describing: location!.coordinate.longitude))]")
            //safely unwrapping user location
            guard let userLocation = location else{
                return
            }
            //will create a circle query to check for event keys within 600 meters of current user location
            let circleQuery = geoFire1?.query(at: userLocation, withRadius: 2.0)
            //will use that query to fetch results from database
            var queryHandle = circleQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
                //                    print("Key '\(key)' entered the search area and is at location '\(location)'")
                print(key)
                currentEventKeys.append(key)
                for currentKey in currentEventKeys {
                    EventService.show(forEventKey: currentKey, eventCategory: "Home", completion: { (event) in
                        currentEvents.append(event!)
                        completion(currentEvents)
                    })
                }
            })
            circleQuery?.observeReady({
                print("All initial data has been loaded and events have been fired!")
                circleQuery?.removeAllObservers()
            })
        } else {
            print("GeoFire does not contain a location for \"firebase-hq\"")
        }
    })        
}
```

Everything else seems to be working and I am removing the observer but it just doesn't stop pulling events.